# Do I really need to return Type::size_type?

Tags: c++, types, size-type

I often have classes that are mostly just wrappers around some STL container, like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  typedef std::vector<whatever> Vec;
  typedef Vec::size_type size_type;
  const Vec& GetVec() { return vec_; }
  size_type size() { return vec_.size() }
private:
  Vec vec_;
};
```

I am not so sure about returning `size_type`. Often, some function will call `size()` and pass that value on to another function and that one will use it and maybe pass it on. Now everyone has to include that Foo header, although I'm really just passing some size value around, which should just be `unsigned int` anyway ...? What is the right thing to do here? Is it best practice to really use `size_type` everywhere?

Comment: Could we have discovered another "virus" in C++: `Container::size_type` which must be propagated through each layer of abstraction? :)

Comment: "Often" having classes that are just wrappers around some STL container strikes me as a code smell.  If you make better use of STL's algorithms and other facilities, you may not need to wrap the containers in order to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Hmm, I tend to prefer to write a wrapper class rather than just using `typedef`, because I might want to add functionality at some point. But it's true, often I could as well just `typedef` and later refactor if really necessary.

Comment: @dehmann: Well, functionality can be added as free-functions, which is preferred anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

STL defines these types as an abstract interface for containers. It is intended to support any type of backing storage. That might be NUMA or disk-backed storage, where `size_type` and `ptr-type` are different from those for system memory. Or - in a NUMA architecture - it might be a specific memory node that's fast, and can work with a very small `size_type` and `ptr_type` - which is a relevant optimization on many architectures.

At least, that were the design goals, also driven by anticipation what *could* be platforms supporting C++. Some early concessions also allowed shortcuts for STL implementers that basically disable this flexibility, and I've never worked with an STL implementation that made use of this. I'd say that's because linear memory access has become much less of a problem, and STL development at that level isn't actually easy.

Still, how much does it hurt you? It would be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 8):

It *should* be `vector<>::size_type` like you have, this is the most correct way.

That said, I know many people, including myself, will just use `size_t` instead. Although it's not mandated to be the same, `vector<>::size_type` is `size_t` for every implementation I know. You should be fine with that.

Comment: +1: Not truly portable or conformant, but I do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it should be size_t and not unsigned int, for 64-bit compatibility. As wrapper class writer, I would return size_type. As class client, I would cast it to appropriate type (size_t), if it is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not so sure about returning
>   size_type. Often, some function will
>   call size() and pass that value on to
>   another function and that one will use
>   it and maybe pass it on. Now everyone
>   has to include that Foo header...

It's fine to return the `size_type`, but this doesn't mean another function should necessarily take the same `size_type` as typedeffed in your class. There exist conversions between integral types. Be brave and just use `size_t`.

You can't overload functions anyway so that there would be one that works with `size` of vector, another for size of `deque` etc, just in case they all happen to be using a different `size_type` (which the standard probably permits). - But you could also use templates, if possible, to deduce the correct `size_type` to use from the argument.

Answer (score -1):

One option you could consider is inheriting from `std::vector` :

```
typedef std::vector<whatever> Foo_Vec;

class Foo : public Foo_Vec
{
public:
    const Foo_Vec &GetVec() { return (Foo_Vec&)*this; }
};
```

I am by no means saying this is the best approach, as it can introduce issues that wouldn't occur by having a private member or inheriting from `private Foo_Vec`, as `public Foo_Vec` exposes all methods on `std::vector` to `Foo`.  Moreover, `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor, so if you attempt to clean up a collection of `std::vector`'s with a Foo tucked in there, it won't get cleaned up entirely.  I'm just throwing it out there.

As other answers suggest, you should use `size_t` or `size_type` instead of `unsigned int` for 64-bit compatibility.  Otherwise, in a future 64-bit build, your `std::vector` could have more than 2<sup>32</sup> items, but the size value would be truncated, leading to bugs.

Comment: questionable, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate

Comment: Because std::vector does not have a virtual destructor. You should never inherit from the standard library, unless it's a class that's been specifically marked as such. -1.