# How to define an iterator in a std::map class

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, compiler-errors

I need help with defining a specialty `map`, I cannot get a specialty map::iterator to compile right.

How do I need to define this iterator for the `find()` call?

Code:

```
// My case-insensitive-less functor, which has historically worked fine for me:
struct ci_less : std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
{
  // case-independent (ci) compare_less binary function
  struct nocase_compare : public std::binary_function<unsigned char,unsigned char,bool>
  {
    bool operator() (const unsigned char& c1, const unsigned char& c2) const {
      return tolower (c1) < tolower (c2);
    }
  };
  bool operator() (const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2) const {
    return std::lexicographical_compare (s1.begin (), s1.end (),
                                         s2.begin (), s2.end (),
                                         nocase_compare());  // comparison
  }
};

//My offending code:
template <class T>
class CaseInsensitiveMap : public map<string, T, ci_less>
{
 public:
// This one actually works, but it requires two "find()" calls.
// I can't ethically call find twice.
  const T* lookup(const T& key) const {
    if (find(key) == map<string, T, ci_less>::end()) return 0;
    else                                             return &find(key)->first;
  }
// This one complains with errors shown below.
  T* lookup(const T& key) {
    CaseInsensitiveMap<T>::iterator itr = find(key);
    if (itr == map<string, T, ci_less>::end()) return 0;
    else              return itr->second;
  }
};
```

Errors:

> In member function `'T* CaseInsensitiveMap<T>::lookup(const T&)'`:
>       error: expected `';'` before `'itr'`
>       error: `'itr'` was not declared in this scope

Comment: I don't think `std::map` was meant to be inherited from.

Comment: In the future, please post your code and errors inline rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `typename` keyword to your variable's type:

```
typename CaseInsensitiveMap<T>::iterator itr = find(key);
```

Anyway, you shouldn't inherit STL containers. Read about why you shouldn't do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate).

**Edit**: Since all you're implementing is a case insenstitive map, you can implement it this way, without inheriting `std::map`, just providing your own compare object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct nocase_compare {
    bool operator() (const unsigned char& c1, const unsigned char& c2) const {
      return tolower (c1) < tolower (c2);
    }
};

struct map_comparer {
  bool operator() (const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2) const {
    return std::lexicographical_compare (s1.begin (), s1.end (),
                                         s2.begin (), s2.end (),
                                         nocase_compare());  // comparison
  }
};

template<class T>
struct CaseInsensitiveMap {
    typedef std::map<std::string, T, map_comparer> type;
};

int main() {
    CaseInsensitiveMap<int>::type my_map;
    my_map["foo"] = 12;
    std::cout << my_map["FoO"] << "\n";
    my_map["FOO"] = 100;
    std::cout << my_map["fOo"] << "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
12
100
```

Answer (score 0):

**typename** CaseInsensitiveMap::iterator itr = find(key);

at line # 31