# Using std::max_element on a stack<int>

Tags: c++, stl, stack

How exactly I can get the max_element of a stack ? STL stack doesn't any `begin()` or `end()` method that I can get the maximum by follow:

```
auto max = max_element(c.begin(), c.end());
```

Comment: The point of `std::stack` is that it's a stack. Choose different or none adapter. Maybe `std::priority_queue` is what you want.

Comment: no , priority_queue  won't work for me , because I need the arrangement as it is. :)

Comment: But you also need to iterate through the container, so you can't have an adapter. Use `std::vector` then. You can still `push_back`, `pop_back` and `back`. `std::stack` simply hides everything else.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428618/trying-to-access-an-index-of-an-stdstack?rq=1. You'd need to sub-class the stack. Preferably with private inheritance.

Comment: @LogicStuff , exactly ! thanks , you can answer it :)

Answer (score 1):

A `std::stack` has a restricted interface, which is the whole point of that abstraction. If not then you could just have used e.g. a `std::deque`. But you have a number of options:

- You can pop all items. If you desire the original stack back at the end then you can just push them back.
- You can access the underlying container (without using a derived class). It's a protected member. The infamous C++ type system loophole for member pointers is helpful, if you're afraid of casting and formally undefined behavior.
- You can use a custom derived class instead of `std::stack` directly.

This list is not exhaustive but they are the more natural options.

I.e. other approaches are fairly unnatural & construed.