# get the sum of stack<int> in c++ without destroying stack

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Efficient way of getting sum of stack elements, without emptying it or copying it to other stack?
What I am doing is:

```
    stack<int> si;
    int sum = 0;
    stack<int> tsi(si);
    while (!tsi.empty()) {
        sum += tsi.top();
        tsi.pop();
    }
```

This can be done using https://ideone.com/i7ha2j midified verson of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428630/7267150

Any other way to achieve the requirement (this case, sum)?? I prefer STL (is it possible).

Comment: Why do you use `std::stack` to begin with? Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::stack` is simply a LIFO data structure. It has not been designed for iterating over elements.

Comment: The **point** of a stack is that you only get access to one end. If you need something else, such as being able to look at all the values, then a stack is not the right data structure.

Comment: That's not possible for stack.Use vector if you want random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over `stack` so there isn't an easy way. You can use `dequeue<int>` or `stack<int>` to insert each top element. Then, use another loop to reinsert them back to original `stack<int> si`, if you have to use stack. Otherwise, try to switch to `vector<int>` for easy iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Stack isn't the right container to choose here. You should have a look at [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), following which you could do something of this sort :

```
#include <vector>

std::vector< int > vec;
int sum = 0;
for( auto const & it : vec )
{
  sum += it;
}
```

The main reason for choosing a `std::vector` over a `std::stack` is due to the easier capability to iterate over vectors.