# How would you initialize a const vector of function results using C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, constants

Is it possible to use something like `generate_n` to create a `const vector` of, say, random numbers? I couldn't think of a way to do it without deriving `vector` and doing the assignment in the constructor.

Comment: I know you have an answer for this now, but just FYI deriving `vector` (or other type in `std` namespace not specifically intended to be derived) is [risky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a static helper or a lambda if you wish; move semantics / copy elision as pointed out in the comments will make this pretty cheap since all decent compilers will omit a full copy of the vector returned by the helper. Instead they'll just create the code to fill a single vector and then use that one.

```
std::vector< int > Helper()
{
  const size_t n = 10;
  std::vector< int > x( n );
  std::generate_n( x.begin(), n, someGenerator );
  return x; 
}

const std::vector< int > my_const_vec( Helper() );
```

here is the lambda version:

```
const std::vector< int > my_const_vec( [] ()
  {
    const size_t n = 10;
    std::vector< int > x( n );
    std::generate_n( x.begin(), n, someGenerator );
    return x; 
  }() );
```

Comment: With such a simple helper, most compilers will even elide the copy completely.

Comment: By the way, according to the *current* standard your lambda needs a `-> std::vector<int>`, I think.

Comment: hmm now I'm confused. Tried with gcc4.7 and cl17.00 and they both accept it, but indeed I seem to remember previous versions of both would reject it.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your initialization into a function and declare it "constexpr" so that you can use it to initialize a const expression.

Comment: No need for a `constexpr` here, since he doesn't need a compile time constant expression (which a `std::vector` return can never be, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::transform` as well

```
vector<int> vec(10,1);
transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), func);
```

Where func is:

```
int func(int i)
{
//return a random generated number 
}
```

Comment: that's possible, but the OP asks for a single *const* vector.

Comment: @stijn Ohh yes. But I may use a temporary intermediate vector and then assign it to the `const` vector as even your approach created one in the function being called.