# Vector and []-operator overloading

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have inherited my class from std::vector. Now I want to overload the []-operator.
When I try to assign a new value to my vector, e.g. `v[0]=5,` I should receive the message `OK`.

This is my code (I know, that makes no sense, I'm just playing around):

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
class Vec : public std::vector<int> {
public:
    int operator[](int);
};

int Vec::operator[](int i) {
    (*this)[i] = i;
    std::cout << "OK";
    return 123;
}

int main() {
    Vec v;
    v[0]=5;
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
In member function ‘int Vec::operator[](int)’:
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignmen
In function ‘int main()’:
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: STL containers are not written in a way that are generally inheritable; you should be wrapping them via encapsulation instead for operations you need/want.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to return a reference to your element - however note that even if you did, you'd run into inifinite recursion - your `operator[]` calls itself.

Either way - inheriting from `std::vector` isn't a good idea. Use composition instead.

Comment: So there is no way to overload the []-operator when inheriting from `std::vector`?

Comment: @user1170330 I didn't say that. You can have `int& operator[](int idx) { return std::vector<int>::operator[](idx); }`. It's just not recommended.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to write `return std::vector<double>::operator[](n);` in a shorter way?

Comment: @user1170330 if you don't write it at all, it'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

This *particular* error is caused because you are not returning an `lvalue`, generally defined as something that can appear to the left of an assignment, such as `v[0] = 5;`. You have more problems as pointed out in the other answers but this is the specific issue you face with that error message <sup>(a)</sup>.

The correct specification for overloading the index operator is:

```
int& operator[] (const int nIndex);
```

You have to return a *reference* to the item (so it can be modified) if you want to treat it as an `lvalue`. The following code shows a fix, although obviously all array indexes map to the same value in this simplified case:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Vec : public std::vector<int> {
    public:
        int& operator[] (int);    // <-- note the '&'
    private:
        int xyzzy;
};

int& Vec::operator[] (int idx) {  // <-- note the '&'
    std::cout << "OK\n";
    return xyzzy;
}

int main () {
    Vec v;
    v[0] = 5;
    v[1] = 6;
    std::cout << v[22] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
OK
OK
OK
6
```

In reality, you wouldn't map all indexes to the same value, the code above is simply to illustrate the correct function signature. I haven't bothered to give a more complete example since subclassing classes with non-virtual destructors regularly leads to problems in non-trivial code <sup>(b)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's not usually considered a good idea to subclass `std::vector` since the destructor isn't virtual, so you can get into trouble when trying to destroy an object polymorphically.

You're probably better off using a `has-a` relationship (where your class *contains* a vector) rather than an `is-a` relationship (where you inherit).

That unfortunately means you may have to create a lot of pass-through methods from your class to the underlying vector (although only the ones you need) but it will solve the problem with the destructor.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> See <sup>(a)</sup> :-)

Comment: What is this `v[22]`? I can replace it with any other number. How can I store the values? E.g. store `5` in `v[0]` and `6` in `v[1]` so that I can access them in `main()`?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Why introduce `xyzzy` rather than calling the base's `operator[]`? - doesn't seem as useful an example as it could be (and it's clearly confused user1170330 given the comment above).

Comment: @user1170330 (and Tony D), that was just an example showing how to overload the function correctly (with `&`). Since I'm against overloading vector because it its non-virtual destructor, there seems little point in giving a fuller example which will almost certainly cause you more problems down the track. If you read the rest of the answer, it will advise you what to do - use `has-a` rather than `is-a`. See also the link provided by Joe in a comment to this question above.

Answer (score 3):

The code below illustrates how to call the `operator[]` from the `vector` base class....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vec : std::vector<int>
{
    int& operator[](int n)
    {
        std::cout << "operator[](" << n << ")\n";
        return std::vector<int>::operator[](n);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vec v;
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(20);
    v[0] += 5;
    std::cout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << '\n';
}
```

Output when I run it:

```
operator[](0)
operator[](1)
operator[](0)
15 20
```

Don't take all this talk about "do not inherit from std::vector" *too* seriously: you have to go out of your way to delete a dynamically allocated Vec using a `std::vector<int>*`, or do an accidental by-value slicing copy - and even then it'd probably only bite you if you had added data members.  You should make sure you understand those risks then make your own assessment, but for small utility programs etc. it's *productive* to inherit from such classes sometimes....

Comment: Tony, in fact it's usually only if you add data members that need special cleanup in the destructor (like they've been `new`'ed for example). So you're right that simple programs generally don't need to worry. Unfortunately, nobody tends to pay me for simple programs so I've learned to be careful :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: well, it's really about the bulk and distribution of the client code - whether it's practical to keep the people maintaining the class and its usage aware of the design decision and using it appropriately. Quite agree that in a corporate environment it's usually not worth having to consider those things, let alone justify the decision to your peers, for any team project. But, sometimes I've been nicely paid for work that required little utilities for data extraction and analysis where productivity and code concision/clarity/mobility was most important.

Comment: 'K, I'll give you +1 since you have provided a useful way to get at the underlying data (unlike my answer), and at least made the OP aware of possible issues.

Comment: @paxdiablo: re adding data members - definitely needing special cleanup is an issue for deletion via a base class pointer, but slicing and inability to maintain invariants is still an issue even for `int`, `double` etc..  Important to understand the Liskov Substitution Principle and that functions working on `std::vector<int>&`s will bypass the `Vec::operator[]` and miss any side effects / checks etc. placed in there.  Not adding extra state is a good rule of thumb until the programmer understands all these issues.