# Convert between vector::operator[] and vector::at in C++

Tags: c++, vector, boundary

`vector::at` are quite helpful for boundary checking, but will lead to low speed.
So I am wondering whether there is a way to quickly convert code between `vector::operator[]` and `vector::at`, so that one for release and one for debug.
Like

```cpp
If (DEBUG)
{
// Do with .at
}
else
{
// Do with []
}
```

However, using code like that will import risk that when `Do with .at` are changed, `Do with []` are forgotten to be changed accordingly.

Is there a quick way to convert code between two modes?

Comment: I think that is simply called operator[]. If your standard library is good, then it already has extra checks in debug mode.

Comment: Which compiler and STL are you using? MS STL already does [bound check with `[]` in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290586/995714). And debug/release flag is a compile time setting so you'll need a macro, not a runtime thing like `if`

Comment: There's no real cost using `at()` with release ready production code. So why change it??

Comment: [Automatically check bounds in std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48035379/995714), [Compile time triggered range check for std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24246017/995714)

Comment: *but will lead to low speed* -- `if ( index >= size )` -- What type of application are you developing where the `if` statement will result in such a "low speed"?

Comment: First should should benchmark your code and actually show a slowdown for vector::at. Often the check can be optimized away or can be done while waiting for some other opcodes and the difference is well below the noise level. On the other hand a single cought bounds check can save you hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like
>
> ```
> If (DEBUG)
> {
> // Do with .at
> }
> else
> {
> // Do with []
> }
> ```

You get something like this by using `operator[]` and by enabling bounds checking debug mode of the standard library implementation that you use. How to do that, and whether that option exists depends on what implementation you use.

Note that typically the entire project, including all libraries must have been built with the same standard library options. This is a potential problem if you use pre-built libraries.

A universally portable solution is to write a wrapper function that conditionally calls one function or the other depending on build configuration. Downside is that this requires changing all code using the wrapped function to use the custom one.