# How to support MySet<int>::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm doing an exercise and encounter a problem.
To solve this exercise, I have to write a template class MySet as a wrapper of STL::set.
In the following, there is code like
`pair<MySet<int>::iterator, MySet<int>::iterator> p` where pair comes from the STL.
Now what should I do to support `MySet<int>::iterator`?
I've tried `typedef set<T>::iterator MySet<T>::iterator`
and `typedef T* iterator` but they all failed.

===============================EDIT================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class Q = greater<T> >
class MySet
{
public:
    using iterator = typename set<T, Q>::iterator;
    typedef typename set<T, Q>::iterator iterator;
    set<T, Q> tset;
    void insert(T value)
    {
        tset.insert(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MySet<int> intset;
    intset.insert(5);
    intset.insert(10);
    MySet<int>::iterator p;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
template<class T>
class MySet
{
public:
    //using iterator = typename set<T>::iterator; // if with c++11
    typedef typename set<T>::iterator iterator; // if without c++11
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Trying `typedef set<T>::iterator iterator` failed.  error: need 'typename' before 'std::set<T>::iterator' because 'std::set<T>' is a dependent scope|  `using iterator = set<T>::iterator` failed either. (my compiler doesn't support c++11)

Comment: I followed your advice and wrote a test, but still not work. See my new EDIT.

Comment: @user3505816 [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c11dd8aa8f707f2) compiles

Comment: Yes, indeed. It seems the website using compiler which support c++11 while my dosen't. Is there any other way to solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: @user3505816 I mean comment out `using iterator = typename set<T, Q>::iterator;` in your code

Comment: Wow it works! I'm new to this syntax, would you please explain it a little?

Comment: @user3505816 [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) and [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from std::set like this:

```
    template <typename T>
    class MySet: public std::set<T>
   {

   };

   int main()
   {
     MySet<int>::iterator itr;
     // do other things

     return 0;
   }
```

Although inheriting STL containers is not a good practice. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)