# Subclassing C++ Map/Dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary

My class inherits from a map object:

This is the method I am trying to implement:

```
double MyCustomClass::returnValueForKey(string key){
    return this->find(key); //<--- No Viable conversion from iterator
}
```

How can I get something like this to work?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to extend off standard containers.

Comment: I absolutely dislike the way C++ names some of its methods. It makes it much easier for the user to understand what is trying to happen.

Comment: What if I made this CustomClass just a normal object and then added a map<string, double> to it and then implemented my methods this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Map object you are talking about is `std::Map` it would be a much better idea to make an `std::Map` object a member of your `MyCustomClass` and extend the functionality this way.

Aside from some design reasons that could be considered subjective, the real sin here would be to extend a class that does not have a virtual destructor.

This would mean that when you call `delete` on one of your `MyCustomClass` objects the destructor of the parent class would never be called.

Comment: Thanks for your post Oliver. That is exactly what I am going to do!

Answer (score 2):

To solve the mechanical problem of getting the code to compile you would simply need to dereference the resulting iterator:

```
return find(key)->second;
```

Of course this is a bad solution because the question itself begins from a position where we have already made bad choices.

1. Why not simply use the `[]` operator instead of this custom code?
2. Why even derive from `std::map` in the first place? This is [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate) and whatever the problem is, there are almost certainly better ways to solve it.
3. Even if this code were correct, what happens when `key` does not exist in the map?

Comment: Thanks for your post John. I am not going to extend off the map class. But to answer your question for number three, this method only gets executed if the key exists.