# C++ Error reading characters of string

Tags: c++, list, templates, pointers, inheritance

I've been reading a lot on the internet about this error and why is would be caused, but I can't find the fault in my code.

I have an `Inventory` class that inherits a list to `GameObject` pointers:

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <list>

template <class GameObject>
class Inventory : public std::list<GameObject*>
{
    private:
    public:
        Inventory() : std::list<GameObject*>::list() {}
};

#endif
```

`GameObject` class looks like this:

```
class GameObject : public Updateable
{
private:
    ...
    Inventory<GameObject*> m_inventory;
public:
    ...
    void SetInventory(Inventory<GameObject*> inventory);
    Inventory<GameObject*>& GetInventory();
};
```

Then I populate  a new `Inventory` object via this method:

```
Inventory<GameObject*>& GameInitializer::ConfigureItems(XMLElement* xmlGameObject) {
    Inventory<GameObject*>* inv = new Inventory<GameObject*>();
    ...

    while (currElement != NULL) {
        GameObject* item = new GameObject();
        // Configure all properties of the item
        item->SetId(currElement->Attribute("id"));
        item->SetPropertyHolder(ConfigureProperties(currElement));
        item->SetName(item->GetPropertyHolder().GetProperty("NAME").As<string>());
        // Add item to inventory
        (*inv).push_back(&item);
        currElement = currElement->NextSiblingElement();
    }
    return (*inv);
}
```

But whenever the reference to this `Inventory` object is returned, the member variables in `GameObject` class (`id`, `name`) are unable to read from memory:

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but might be useful: [About inheriting from STL containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)

Comment: This code would benefit greatly from the use of [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: Just to make sure, are you aware that `m_inventory` ends up inheriting from `std::list<GameObject**>`? I think one `*` would be enough, but I'm not sure whether your code needs two.

Comment: If so, I would recommend renaming the template argument of the `Inventory` class to distinguish it from your class with the same name. Might clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second code block you `push_back()` a pointer to a local variable (i.e. `GameObject* item`). It gets destroyed on returning and makes the IDE point this error out.

Comment: Better recheck that.  It looks to me that `item` is allocated on the heap using `new` and is therefore *not* destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: The item pointed to by `item` is not destroyed but he uses a pointer to the pointer itsself, which is a local variable.

Comment: Ok, I see it now, but I cant write this: 

    (*inv).push_back(item);

Comment: Either allocate the pointer on the heap (what seems weird, at least to me), or rerwrite push_back to copy the pointer by value.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend changing this:

```
Inventory<GameObject*> m_inventory;
```

to this:

```
Inventory<GameObject> m_inventory;
```

so it will be an `std::list<GameObject*>` instead of `std::list<GameObject**>`.

Storing pointer-to-pointer-to-`GameObject` elements seems redundant, and storing simply pointers to `GameObject` should be enough, and make your other code simpler (such as this line: `(*inv).push_back(&item)`).

Comment: Thank you su much, that's the cause for all my problems I think

Comment: I think the cause for all your problems is having the same name for both the `GameObject` class and the `GameObject` template argument ;) Template arguments should be named `T` or something similarly simple to clear up confusion like this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, which was due to me declaring the variable at the top of the function then declaring it again.