# Forward declare a pointer to an STL container?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, forward-declaration

In my header file I want to avoid using #include  but my class will have a vector or a pointer to a vector. I'm content with just a pointer, but I can't figure out how to declare it. Will I have to declare it as a void* and always cast it? That would be lame.

```
// What do I type here to forward declare vector?

class Counters
{
    Counters();

    void inc(const char* s);

    void print();

    void clear();

private:
    std::vector<int>* Counts;
    int total;
};
```

Please note carefully that I only want a POINTER TO a container to be stored in my class, NOT a container. The size of pointers is known without needing to refer to the declaration of the container, so please do not answer that this can't be done because the compiler needs to know the container declaration.

Comment: *"In my header file I want to avoid using #include"* That's the problem right there, just include what you need.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `#include <vector>`? There shouldn't be any harm doing so.

Comment: Forward declarations exist for a reason, guys. There is tons of literature on pruning #includes to reduce recompilation, improve compile times, improve portability, break circular dependencies, etc. In my case this declaration will be consumed by the CUDA compiler as well as the main C++ compiler and it's well worth trying to avoid including too much crap in code that CUDA will be parsing. Trust me.

Comment: @Brian, this is NOT a duplicate. I studied the question "Forward declare an STL container?" thoroughly before I posted. There are enormous differences between forward declaring a pointer and a data structure. My case is easy for the compiler; I just need to figure out the syntax of the forward declaration.

Comment: @AlltheRage I know the question is different, but the answer is the same. You cannot forward declare `std::vector` or other standard library containers, because it's undefined behaviour in most cases to add your own declarations to `namespace std`.

Comment: _"so please do not answer that this can't be done because the compiler needs to know the container declaration."_ — Yes. That's exactly what the compiler needs to know. A member `T*` requires `T` to be declared.

Comment: "Trust me" he says. Just accept that it's not really doable, and certainly not worth doing. #include <vector> will not hurt your compile times, won't cause unnecessary recompilation (it should never change), won't hurt portability (it's part of the standard!), won't cause circular dependencies, or any of the other parade of horribles you've heard. What you want to do is premature optimization, the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works in your situation:

```
//header
struct Container;

struct Foo{
    Container *container;
};

//cpp
#include <vector>

struct Container : std::vector<int>{

};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.container = new Container;
    foo.container->push_back(42);
}
```

Comment: Don't inherit from standard containers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate The pimpl idiom would otherwise be fine.