# Subclassing STL-Containers: Range Constructors don't work

Tags: c++, templates, stl, allocator

Many STL containers have a range constructor that you can use to initialize the container elements:

```
char ary[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
vector<char> v(ary, ary + 3);
```

I subclass specific STL containers, solely for the purpose of using a custom allocator by default:

```
template<class _Ty, class _Ax = stl_allocator<_Ty> >
class xvector
    : public std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>
{
};
```

This works well, but I can't use the range constructor anymore:

```
xvector<char> v2(ary, ary + 3);
```

Generates the following error:

```
error C2661: 'xvector<_Ty>::xvector' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
    with
    [
        _Ty=char
    ]
```

However, I can use the assign method:

```
xvector<char> v3;
v3.assign(ary, ary + 3);
```

Can someone explain why the range-constructor doesn't work while the assign method does? I'm using VC++ 2008 and from what I can tell the argument list of the range constructor and the assign method is exactly the same.

**Update**
Thank you for your answers, but for me the key-point is that I forgot that constructurs aren't inherited and so only the default constructor is available (it doesn't have anything to do with range-constructors).

I also should have mentioned that I'm forced to stick to VS2008 / C++ 03 because the target platform doesn't support more recent compilers, unfortunately.

Comment: Don't inherit from C++ Standard Library containers.

Comment: *"I subclass specific STL containers, solely for the purpose of using a custom allocator by default:"* XY-Problem. Use `template <class T, class A = stl_allocator<T>> using xvector= std::vector<T, A>;` instead and done.

Comment: Also, identifiers like `_Ty` are implementation reserved, you cannot use them.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - An alias template in VC++ 2008? Did it even support it back then?

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok, probably not. But then they can't inherit constructors either. Time to update to a less ancient compiler I would say.

Comment: There is still the old alias way `template <class T, class A = stl_allocator<T>> struct xvector { typedef std::vector<T, A> type; };` and `xvector<int>::type`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using VC++ 2008

Which means you probably don't have access to C++11. Constructors aren't inherited, and prior to C++11 there was no way to even specify a c'tor *should* be inherited. In C++03 you have as far as I can tell two options:

1. Redefine all of `std::vector`'s constructors, and have them forward to the base class c'tor. That's brittle, and likely won't play well with upgrading your tool-chain. I say that because the definition of `std::vector`'s constructors have changed between C++03 and C++11. You'd need to resort to some unpleasantness to make it work.
2. Use aliasing instead of inheritance:

   ```
   template<class Ty, class Ax = stl_allocator<Ty> >
   struct xvector
   {
       typedef std::vector<Ty, Ax> type;
   };
   ```

   You can't use `xvector<...>` directly anymore, instead having to use `xvector<...>::type`, but the type you get this way *is a `std::vector`*. And it's more toolchain-upgrade-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

inheriting from stl containers is a bad idea as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)

but if you objective is

> using a custom allocator by default

with c++11 you can do

```
template<class _Ty, class _Ax = stl_allocator<_Ty> >
using xvector = std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>;
```