# Recursive variant output compiles but segfault at runtime

Tags: c++, recursion, variant

So I wrote an object that could handle JSON-like content, of which there is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant> 

struct Array;
struct Value;

struct Array: public std::vector<Value>{
    using std::vector<Value>::vector;
};

struct Value: public std::variant<bool, int, Array>{
    using std::variant<bool, int, Array>::variant;
};
```

Now I wanted to overload the output stream operator. Here is the code:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Value value);
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Array array);

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Array array){
    for (auto &a : array){
        os << a << ", ";
    }
    return os;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Value value){
    os << value;
    return os;
}
```

Now, if I try to run it :

```
int main()
{
    Array a {1,2,3}; // OK
    std::cout << a;  // Segfault
}
```

Where's the catch ?

EDIT As pointed, there was a recursion loop.

Comment: What did you observe, when stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Be aware of [the risks of inheriting from standard containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate).

Comment: You have a segfault, so you have a stack trace or easy access to one. Look at it.

Comment: Note that your operators copy your `Array` and `Value`.

Comment: ... and the `Value`, which may also contain an `Array` (in general).

Comment: In the `operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Value value)` case, what did you expect `os << value` to do?

Comment: @Useless That's something I never did, before, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger - it will also (on any sane system) handle the segfault for you, or load a core file once you have one.

Comment: Clang warns about it, https://wandbox.org/permlink/XFdStZJjMPTQMHka .

Answer (score 4):

You have a stack overflow due to infinite recursion:

> ```
> std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Value value){
>     os << value; // call to self
>     return os;
> }
> ```

This would be a correct way to insert a variant into a stream:

```
std::visit([&](const auto& value) {
    os << value;
}, static_cast<const Value::variant&>(value));
```

Comment: The fix (simply deleting that operator) might be mentioned?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't think that would work. I added a fix though.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eerorika Ah, yes, `variant` doesn't expose an `operator<<` overload.