# Error with going through map elements with a class pointer as values

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a class that i'm using for a trie

```
class Node {
public:
    map<char,Node*> node;
    bool flag = false;
};

int main(){
    Node table;
    for(auto x: table){}
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through it's elements but I keep getting errors

I checked stack for solutions and tried to use the iterator map method :

```
error: 'class Node' has no member named 'begin'
for (it = table->begin(); it != table->end(); it++){
                ^~~~~
error: 'class Node' has no member named 'end'
    for (it = table->begin(); it != table->end(); it++){
```

Also tried to use a for loop and got a similar error:

```
error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
for(auto x: table){
            ^~~~
```

How can I iterate through the elements in another way or how can I fix these errors?

Comment: what's the type of `table`?

Comment: The table is of type (Node*)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows exactly what you're writing and what errors you get.

Comment: Doesn't change when I change it though

Comment: Your class `Node` should inherit `std::map` publicly.

Comment: @KaiserKatze That is dubious advice because standard containers are not designed to be polymorphic. I can work, but you have to beware of object slicing. Additionally standard containers do not have a `virtual` destructor so you also have to be careful how you store your derived type. See [Is it okay to inherit implementation from STL containers, rather than delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate). Deriving from standard containers should not be recommended without mentioning the caveats.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Upvoted your comment. I didn't realize such an issue before. Thank you for your lesson. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node` is not an iterable class.  It's just a regular class, that happens to have a `std::map` as a member.  What you want is to access the `map` object within `Node:

`for (auto x : table->node)`

Also, in the code you showed us, `table` is never initialized.  I am assuming that in your real code, it is, but if not, fix that too.  You can either use `new Node` to create an object, or else declare it as a value and not a pointer: `Node table;`