# How can I create a vector with a maximum length?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I want to create a container that provides all of the same functionality as a `std::vector` but with the caveat that you cannot add anymore elements once the vector reaches a specified size.

My first thought was to inherit from `std::vector` and do something like

```cpp
template <typename T, unsigned int max>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T> {
  public:
    // override push_back, insert, fill constructor, etc...
    // For example:
    virtual void push_back(const T& var) override {
      if (this.size() < max) vec.push_back(var);
    }
};
```

But then I learned that inheriting STL containers is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate).

Second thought was to create a wrapper class, i.e.

```cpp
template <typename T, unsigned int max>
class MyVector {
  private:
    std::vector<T> vec;
  public:
    // Wrappers for every single std::vector function...
    iterator begin() { return vec.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return vec.begin(); }
    //and on and on and on...etc.
};
```

But this smells bad to me. Seems very difficult to maintain.

Am I missing something obvious, should I try an alternative approach?

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is only bad if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Inherit privately.

Comment: Be aware that the maximum size of a `std::vector` may be quite different than the available memory size (available to your process).

Comment: Concerning your second thought: when you design a container you decide what operations it should support, and you implement those operations. For a vector-like class, much of the bookkeeping has already been done for you, and many of the functions that your wrapper class provides simply forward to a stored data member of type `vector`. They're trivial to write and to maintain. A few need more than what the vector provides, and you write code accordingly. You could, of course, write your entire class from scratch, and that would be much more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Why not use a non-member function taking the vector and the element as usual parameters and the max as a template parameter (or usual...)?

Comment: @prog-fh These vectors are exposed through an API. Currently, users can take them past a set limit causing segmentation issues further down the road. I'm trying to cut this problem off at the source instead of adding length checks everywhere the vectors are used, which would be even harder to maintain.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux private inheritance seems most attractive currently.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Asker linked to that exact question in the original question, he's aware of it.

Comment: @DevinTrowbridge -- [Boost already has done this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html).  You can see how they implemented this, or just use boost (this particular class is header-only, so no external linking of a library is required).

Comment: If you are trying to stop other developers from resizing a `std::vector` past a certain size, then you need to somehow convince/force them to use length checks.   There isn't some way to magically force that on them (e.g. by deriving a class from `std::vector` or (better) containing it in another class that enforces constraints) if they use `std::vector` and its operations directly.    Also, if exceeding some reduced size limit on a `std::vector` causes "segmentation issues" then some other code (e.g. which is using vector elements out of bounds) is the culprit - you need to find/fix that code

Comment: @Peter I ended up going with your suggestion. I don't want to remove the features of std::vector from my users. I am just length checking the vectors elsewhere, dropping excess elements, and warning devs that the elements were dropped. I think this offers the most familiar API at the cost of maintainability on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a vector with a maximum length?

You cannot do that with `std::vector`. You can however refrain from inserting any elements after you reach some limit. For example:

```
if (v.size() < 10) {
    // OK, we can insert
}
```

> I want to create a container that provides all of the same functionality as a `std::vector` but with the caveat that you cannot add anymore elements once the vector reaches a specified size.

That, you can do.

> ```
> virtual void push_back(const T& var) override {
> ```

`std::vector::push_back` isn't virtual, so you may not `override` it.

Also, I recommend considering whether the push back should be silently ignored in the case `max` is reached.

> But then I learned that inheriting STL containers is bad.

To be more specific, **publicly** inheriting them is a bit precarious.

Using private inheritance, you can use `using` to pick the members that you wish to delegate directly, and implement the differing members manually.

> Seems very difficult to maintain.

The standard library doesn't change very often, and the vector class hasn't changed much so far, and changes have been quite simple, so "very difficult" is debatable - although subjective of course.

You could use meta-programming to make it maintainable. But that may be bit of an over-engineered approach.

Comment: This does answer the question that I asked. I will mention that I ended up keeping the vanilla `std::vector`s and length check them via a free-function. More difficult on my end to maintain, but I think its worth having the optimizations and familiarity the STL offers.